# Is it possible to embed directly a SVG code in an "image element" in the map composer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, mapping, svg

I'm trying to implement custom SVG files in the map composer, I was able to add everything I wanted through HTML elements, but I want to add a custom "functional" North Arrow so I need to use the "image element".

PS: I know I can use a URL but I want to avoid using that method.

[image: Example]

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you need to upgrade to qgis 3.14

Comment: And I guess someone with an older version is not going to be able to see my custom svg image right?

Comment: Correct- qgis projects aren't backward compatible